# Why Is Horizontal Tab not working for C++ cout?

Tags: c++, tabs

I have this simple output statement:

```
cout<<"John\tWilliam\tSmith"<<endl;
```

However, when I compile and run the output I get is slightly off. For example,

```
John   William Smith
```

The first tab works correctly, but the second tab seems to be ignored for some reason. Any help?

Comment: What's the default tab size set in your terminal?

Comment: You better use [setw()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) or try use double tabs `"...\t\t..."`

Comment: That ought to be an ***answer,*** FirstStep!  Please make it one. *(I daresay that the same behavior would be seen anytime this particular string were output, no matter what language was doing it, and I think you've hit this therefore-universal "nail" squarely on the head.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use tabs to separate columns; there is no consistent interpretation.

- Tabs can be ignored.
- Tabs can range from 2 spaces to 8 or more.
- Tabs can be substituted by spaces or can advance to columns.
- Tabs can be regularly spaced or variable spaced.
- Tabs suck when used with variable width fonts.

A more consistent method to line up columns is with `setw`. Also be aware of `left` or `right` justification.

When using GUIs, the character spacing must be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Both tabs seem to be working just fine. Rather, it is you who is misunderstanding them!

A tab space isn't a fixed number of whitespaces. A tab space moves the cursor to the next predefined "column". For this reason, it is not very reliable. However it's currently set in your terminal, it's not giving the result you want.

Output a fixed number of whitespaces instead. You'll be much happier.